# <= Operand asking for expected type in Swift?

Tags: swift, int, where-clause, operands

I'm trying to look for items equal or less than zero in my query like so.....

```
for zeroItems in snapshot.value as! NSDictionary where zeroItems.value["Value"] as! Int <= 0
```

I'm getting an `Expected type` error. Please explain and show me how to correct.

Comment: Why are you using NSDictionary in Swift?!

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov I was using NSDictionary because by data is coming from Firebase.

Comment: That's okay, just cast it to a native Swift Dictionary and you'll instantly gain all the benefits of the native Swift types.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider applying a `filter` to simplify the logic to only include elements less than zero. I've created a working example in the [IBM Swift Sandbox](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/583b727e1d7e592e9b35c9fa).

```
import Foundation

// Construct the data structure with demo data
struct Snapshot {
    let value: NSDictionary
}

let dict: NSDictionary = [ "a" : -1, "b" : 0, "c" : 1]
let snapshot = Snapshot(value: dict)

//Apply a filter
let zeroItems = snapshot.value.filter{Int($0.1 as! NSNumber) <= 0}

//View the result
print(zeroItems)
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly you've overused `Any` if you have to use this many `as!` casts in a single line. Create a custom struct for this type and convert the data to that. If you're passing around `NSDictionary` and using `as!` very much, you're fighting the system.

That said, to make this work you probably just need more parentheses. Something like:

```
for zeroItems in (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary) where (zeroItems.value["Value"] as! Int) <= 0
```

But this is horrible Swift, so avoid this if possible.

Comment: Why is it so prevalent to us Foundation datatypes in Swift?! It adds so much needless complexity but people still keep doing it. I don't get it!

Answer (score 1):

You interpreting `snapshot.value` as Dictionary, so `zeroItems` is a tuple of key and value.
As I understand you having array of dictionaries, and you want to filter them by "Value" key, right?

If so then you may use following code:

```
// dictionary with Value key, and Int value
let dict: [String: Any] = ["Value":-1]
// array of dictionaries
let value: [[String: Any]] = [dict, <**add here as many as you want**>]


// get only array of integeres
let onlyIntegers = value.flatMap { $0["Value"] as? Int }.filter {$0 <= 0 }
print(onlyIntegers)


// get array of dictionaries which passes <=0 check 
let onlyLessOrEqualTo0 = value.filter { dict in
    if let value = dict["Value"] as? Int {
        return value <= 0
    }
    return false
}
print(onlyLessOrEqualTo0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, adding some parentheses will help in seeing where the problem is:

```
for zeroItems in myDict as! NSDictionary where (zeroItems.value["Value"] as! Int) <= 0
```

Now, we get "Type 'Any' has no subscript members".  So the problem is that you haven't told Swift what the type is of `zeroItems`'s value, which I think is a dictionary of , judging from your code:

This compiles for me:

```
for zeroItems in myDict as! Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Int>> where zeroItems.value["Value"]! <= 0
```

However, this is not pretty.  You could probably get more readable code using `filter` as was suggested in another answer.